# Не работает! В чем проблема?

Tags: php

Этот скрипт получает файлы из директории, а после выводит ссылку на файл и если пользователь кликает на ссылку, скрипт выводит содержимое файла или можно, чтобы подключал к сценарию, т.к. это нужно.

```
<?php

$fdir = 'grabbed_old';

if(! is_dir($fdir))
    exit('Неверно задана директория.');

if(!empty($_GET['file'])){
    $file = trim($_GET['file']);
    $file = basename($file);
    $f    = end(explode('/', $file));       
    if (substr($file, 0, 1) == '.'){
        print 'Чтение данных файлов запрещено.';    
    }elseif(file_exists($file) && is_readable($file)){
        //тут из вашей задачи не понятно, подключить типа require/include, или все же предоставить на чтение. будем думать что на чтение.
        print htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents($file)); //
        // или include($file);

    }else{
        print 'Файл не найден.';
    }
    print "<br />";     
}

$dir = opendir($fdir);
while($file = readdir($dir)){
    if( is_file($file) && substr($file, 0, 1) != '.' ) //сразу же отрубим файлы типа .htpasswd, .htaccess, и ..
        print "<a href='?file={$fdir}{$file}'>$file</a><br />"; 
}

?>
```

Comment: А что именно не работает то? в чем суть вообще этого скрипта?

Comment: этот скрипт получает файлы из директории, а после выводит ссылку на файл и если пользователь кликает на ссылку скрипт выводит содержимое файла или можно чтобы подключал к сценарию т.к. это нужно

Comment: **Что не работает? Где выводит ошибку или на каком этапе скрипт работает не так, как надо?**

Comment: ошибок не выдает! просто на экран ничего не выводит!

Comment: Может это оттого, что разметка идёт без тегов html/body/etc?

Comment: да нет и с разметкой тоже ничего!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в логике скрипта

```
if (empty($_GET['FileName'])) {
    // Листинг категории
}
else{
    // листинг файла
}
```